MIP constraints for a maximum value
Is there a better way to model a constraint(s) that ensures $x$ is the maximum value among a set of unique variables, say $\{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}$, instead of directly setting $x$ to be greater than or equal to each value as follows:
$x \geq y_i \quad \forall\ i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$
update:
I have a bin packing problem where the profit of a bin is taking as the largest profit of items in the bin not the summation of profits. I found it too exhaustive for the solver when imposing linear constraints ($z_{item, bin} \in \{0, 1\}$)as
$p_{bin} \geq z_{item, bin} \ p_{item} \quad \forall\ item \in items$

If you are not constraining $x$ from above or have an objective that minimizes $x$, you are not sure $x=\max{y_1,…,y_n}$ with your constraints

Supporting the point made by @Sune, I suggest you look at the accepted answer to this question.

I have a bin packing problem where the profit of a bin is taking as the largest profit of items in the bin not the summation of profits. I found it too exhaustive for the solver when imposing linear constraints to get the profit of a bin.

Unless you are minimizing profit, those constraints will not do what you want.  What prevents taking $p_\text{bin}\to\infty$?

@RobPratt Thank you, Professor. Yes, the goal is to minimize profit, and I apologize for any confusion caused earlier. I referred to it as the bin packing problem to help make it more relatable. Following the same paradigm, the objective here is to minimize profit when assigning all items to bins with different capacities, where the profit of each bin is determined by the largest profit of any item in it. I am currently exploring ways to model the constraint (s) that captures the profit of each bin, rather than relying on linear constraints.

You might be interested in this blog post about a similar problem, where the "profit" (unhappiness) of a "bin" (table) is determined by pairs of "items" (guests): https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2014/11/10/do-you-have-an-uncle-louie-optimal-wedding-seat-assignments/
